# Reusing Receive/SendReply in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

How can Receive/SendReply be reused in WF (4)?
E.g

```
Receive/SendReply (Start)
Process data
Decision (data is valid?)
  True
    Pick
      1) Receive/SendReply (Confirm)
      2) Receive/SendReply (Input data)
      3) Receive/SendReply (Restart)
  False
    Pick
      1) Receive/SendReply (Input data)
      2) Receive/SendReply (Restart)
```

It should be possible to call `Input data` and `Restart` in two different `Pick`s.

Currently I'm using WF 4, but I'd like to hear if 4.5 has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a custom composite activity and add the Receive/SendReply pair to that and reuse the that custom activity in multiple places. This has been the basic reuse mechanism in WF4 since its release.

Comment: How about if one needs to put `Receive` in the `Trigger` and `SendReply` in the `Action` of the `PickBranch`? Is it possible to create reusable `PickBranch`?

Comment: The PickBranch activity is sealed so not much you can do there. The best option would be to create a Sequence with the preconfigued Receive and another with the preconfigured SendReply. That said in quite a few cases you can get away with the Receive/SendReply pair in the PickBranch trigger.

Answer (score 0):

PickBranch is sealed, so you can't go the x:Class route. It's a hack, but you may be able to use a custom MarkupExtension to achieve your needs.